# How to set response as header value in Nginx auth

Tags: authentication, nginx, header, request

Pardon me if I am asking a poor standard question, I am thinking of using Nginx as proxy layer for my api,Here is what I want to do

```
NGINX -------- auth request ----> AUTH PROXY
                                       |
  |     <---200 + Response   <------ SUCCESS
  |
  ----> underlying request + Response from auth call ----> BACKEND SERVER
```

The problem is I am not able to figure out how to add header value as response in nginx auth

this is my conf

```
location / {                                               
    auth_request      /_auth;                             
    auth_request_set $user <Response Value>;       
    proxy_set_header x-user $user;                  
    proxy_pass       http://backend_server;                
}                                                          

location = /_auth {                                       
    internal;                                              
    proxy_pass https://auth;          
    proxy_pass_request_body off;                           
    proxy_set_header Content-Length "";                    
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You mean, from response body?

Comment: Well, it would be much easier to put response into http header and use `$upstream_http_...` variable.